# how to access value of a input tag in a component through another component in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to react and js basically.
I want to access the value of input in Input so that I can give the person a hint while he is typing (for example he types New and He sees New york as like a placeholder for that input form).
Any help would be appreciated.

**Note that I can only change the app.js file**

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from './Input.js';
import Cities from './cities.json';

function App() {
   return <div>
      <Input
      />
   </div>
}

export default App;
```

input.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = ({handleChange, hint}) => {
  return (
    <div className="input">
      <label htmlFor="input" data-testid="hint">
        {hint}
      </label>
      <input
        data-testid="input"
        type="text"
        id="input"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Your App component will useState to store your value of the Input, which you update by passing a handleChange function.  That way your App has the necessary information to pass down hints.

Comment: Try something like this `<Input handleChange={(e) => alert("the value I'm looking for: "+e.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The simplest one would be to set up state in your App component to keep track of the input's value, and pass the input component a `handleChange` function that updates the state:

```
function App() {
   // set up state to keep track of the input value
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

   // declare a function to update the state when the input changes
   const handleChange = event => setInputValue(event.target.value);

   // pass the value and the change handler to the input
   return <div>
      <Input
        value={inputValue}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
   </div>
}
```

With this setup, the App component knows (and is in charge of) the input's value and can do other things with it.

The `event` argument passed to the handler will contain all the information you need about the input via its [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, including the new value.

Read up on [useState here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [controlled inputs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function App() {
    // set up state to keep track of the input value
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

    // declare a function to update the state when the input changes
    const handleChange = (event) => setInputValue(event.target.value);

    // pass the value and the change handler to the input
    return (
    <div>
    <Input value={inputValue} handleChange={handleChange} />
     <Button type="submit" handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
      );
      }
```

export default function Button({ handleSubmit }) {
return (

Submit

);
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).